# Self hosting Supabase using Postgres

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I am trying to self host Supabase with Postgersql (AWS RDS). I have got the db up and running.

I download their docker diretory. It's working fine with the default settings, but when I do it with my postgreSQL,
supabase-auth doesnt seem to work. It give me following error

```
supabase-auth | time="2022-07-15T14:09:51Z" level=fatal msg="running db migrations: Migrator: problem creating schema migrations: CREATE TABLE \"schema_migrations\" (\n\"version\" VARCHAR (14) NOT NULL\n);\nCREATE UNIQUE INDEX \"schema_migrations_version_idx\" ON \"schema_migrations\" (version);: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in (SQLSTATE 3F000)"
supabase-auth | [POP] 2022/07/15 14:09:51 info - 2.6074 seconds
supabase-auth exited with code 1
```

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Amazon Aurora? 

Have you tried to migrate the default postgres following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Migrating.html)?

Comment: I am using AWS RDS..

Comment: Are you using `Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL` or `Amazon Aurora with PostgreSQL compatibility`?  

If you are, which one of them?

Both are AWS RDS options.

Comment: Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL

Comment: Have you tried to migrate your project from the default postgres into the RDS postgres?

https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database#migrating-between-projects

Comment: Actually, I am spinning a fresh supabase instance.